# I have a VB code to add a row in excel, but it keeps deleting the formulas in all columns

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have some VBA code in excel to add a row when I click a button. The problem is that the formulas are deleted in the rows when I click the "Add Row" button.

The code is this:

```
Sub AddRow()
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
End Sub
```

I cannot think of a way to get around this problem. I'm by no means fluent in coding at all. I obtained the code from a youtube video that looked like it would help me with adding rows.

An example of the formulas that I have entered in is:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Cuvette Packaging",$C$105:$C$419)),$B$105:$B$1276,"")
```

I just can't seem to find out how to get around the code to not delete what I have in all of my columns.

Comment: I don't see how this is deleting anything. You are adding a row below your last blank row. This row will be blank by default

Comment: If you insert a row anywhere by just doing `right click > insert` you will find a blank row or column (depending on the insert)

Comment: Try copying the row above rather than inserting and the clear the cells that don’t contain formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this ...

```
Sub AddRow()
    Dim lngLastRow As Long, rngActiveCell As Range

    ' Rename "Sheet1" to the name of your worksheet.
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lngLastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        ' Get the active cell, we'll make sure we reselect it after the copy operation completes.
        Set rngActiveCell = ActiveCell

        ' Turn screen updating off.
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        ' Copy and paste the last row to the row below.
        .Rows(lngLastRow).Copy
        .Rows(lngLastRow + 1).PasteSpecial

        ' Select the previously active cell.
        rngActiveCell.Select

        On Error Resume Next

        ' Clear the cells that do not contain formulas.
        .Rows(lngLastRow + 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents

        On Error GoTo 0

        ' Do some clean up work.
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

There are few other things that may need to be thrown in but go with that as a start.

[image]

I hope it helps.